# Encrypting to AES256 CBC in PHP with a 40 character key

Tags: php, ruby, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to wrap my head around mcrypt_cbc. I have a 40 character key (OAuth key - doing the encryption/signing manually instead of using an OAuth library) to use, but I'm not sure how I should be using this.

End result needs to be a json pair encrypted to SHA256 CBC, and that encoded in base64. What I have is..

```
$key = '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890';
$pair = 'user:pass';
$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,$key,$pair,MCRYPT_ENCRYPT,""));
```

I'm sure this isn't right, but I have the following questions:

If I read the PHP documentation correctly, RIJNDAEL_128 can used for for SHA256 - is this correct?

For the Key and IV.. I have seen the following as well:

```
$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,substr($key,0,32),$pair,MCRYPT_ENCRYPT,substr($key,32,16)));
```

I'm a bit puzzled - the first 32 characters are used for the key, and the remaining 16 are for an IV? Is the IV always just a section of the key? And how would this be done for 40 characters? Using an IV of...

```
substr($key,32,8)
```

results in

```
The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize
```

The below Ruby code is an example from the API I am referencing, but I have zero knowledge when it comes to Ruby

```
def encrypt_aes(data)
  sha_key = Digest::SHA2.digest(@secret_key)
  aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("AES-256-CBC")    
  aes.encrypt
  aes.key = sha_key
  aes.iv = "\x00" * 16
  encrypted = aes.update(data) + aes.final
  Base64.encode64(encrypted)
end
```

Any guidance at all would be greatly appreciated. I was fairly experienced in PHP back in the day, but cryptography was always my weakest area in general. The most experience I have in it is using the Botan library in c++, and that alone was all thanks to modifying various snippets.

Comment: If you don't know ruby - then take any php oauth library, say `Zend_Oauth`

Comment: @zerkms I was hoping to stay away from utilizing an OAuth library in general, and just manage all the signatures myself, but I am debating it in the long run.

Comment: I meant - get the library that works and see how exactly they prepare the signature. PS: what's the real reason for avoiding libraries?

Comment: @zerkms Hah, I'm smart.. great idea, thanks. I'm trying to keep the overhead as minimal as possible - eventually a c++ app will also be reaching out to these php scripts to pull info from the API. I have yet to find a lightweight, cross platform OAuth library for c++. Since it requires a constant internet connection anyway to read from a mysql database, I figure I can use the same host to just handle API calls as well.

Comment: "the overhead as minimal as possible" --- these days developers' time is much more expensive than computation time. But, it's another story ;-)

Comment: @zerkms If this wasn't just a personal project, I'd completely agree with you :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference for anyone else working on this, this is how I got it working:

```
$CREDENTIALS = 'user:pass';
$SECRET_KEY = 'xxxx'; //40 character secret key

$key256 = @pack("H*" , @hash('sha256', $SECRET_KEY));
$encrypted_string = @base64_encode( openssl_encrypt( $CREDENTIALS, "aes-256-cbc", $key256, true) );
```

Once that was finished, I was able to add that into the URL a 'credentials' parameter, along with other necessary parameters, generate a signature via base64 sha256, then send the signature w/ the parameters out to the api server.